# Select elements through class attribute in jQueryValidator

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, validation, class-attributes

Is it possible to select elements through class attribute using [jQueryValidator](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya you can , By default jquery validation plugin does the validation based on the class. For example, if are you adding class='required' to your input boxes, validation plugin takes that field as required,If you want you even write your own logic using validator.addMethod function.

Answer (score 0):

are you talking about the [equalTo](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/equalTo#other) method ??

as stated there:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    password: "required",
    password_again: {
      equalTo: "#password"
    }
  }
});
```